# Can't seem to install the google-api-php-client correctly

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

There is something going wrong with the google api php client. Even though I followed the installation on github precisely it still wont work. Im not using the Composer way but i downloaded the release. I have tried to use different paths in the response-callback.php require_once like

```
'google-api-php-client/src/google/autoload.php'
'google-api-php-client/vendor_autoload.php'
```

But nothing worked...

Error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Users/mike/Documents/test:/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/php/sdk') in /Users/mike/Documents/test/response-callback.php on line 3
Warning: require_once(google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/mike/Documents/test/response-callback.php on line 3
```

app.yaml:

```
application: csimporttest
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.php
```

main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Hi! Stackoverflow!</h2>

<?php include'response-callback.php';
echo "response-callback file: ", $test; 

?>
<a href="<?php include'response-callback.php'; echo $googleImportUrl; ?>"> Import google contacts </a>
</body>

</html>
```

response-callback.php

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$test = 'WORKS!'; 

$google_client_id = 'SECRET';
$google_client_secret = 'SECRET';
$google_redirect_uri = 'https://csimporttest.appspot.com';

//setup new google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('csimporttest');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

$client -> setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');

$googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();
function curl($url, $post = "") {
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
 if ($post != "") {
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 }
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
 //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
 //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['google_code'])) {
 $auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
 $max_results = 200;
    $fields=array(
        'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
        'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
        'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
        'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
        'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
    );
    $post = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $post = rtrim($post,'&');
    $result = curl('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',$post);
    $response =  json_decode($result);
    $accesstoken = $response->access_token;
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    $xmlresponse =  curl($url);
    $contacts = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);

 $return = array();
 if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
 foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
           //retrieve Name and email address  
 $return[] = array (
 'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
 'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
 );
 } 
 }

 $google_contacts = $return;

 unset($_SESSION['google_code']);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the whole Google php client library in your project folder, then change

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
```

to:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-1-master/src/Google/autoload.php';
```